# How to temporarily disable an address-sanitizer (ASAN) feature at run-time?

Tags: address-sanitizer

Is it possible to temporarily disable a feature of address sanitizer? (ASAN),

For example, a test may intentionally call `malloc(SIZE_MAX)` which is expected to return NULL.

I would like to ignore this error, run the test - then restore the state of ASAN back to what is was previously.

Is this possible?

I tried temporarily using:

```c
setenv("allocator_may_return_null", "1", 1);

... {code body} ...

unsetenv("allocator_may_return_null");
```

But the environment variable was ignored.

Answer (score 1):

[`allocator_may_return_null`](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/SanitizerCommonFlags) isn't the name of an environment variable; rather it is an option that should be specified in the ASAN_OPTIONS<sup>[1]</sup> environment variable. An option and its value in ASAN_OPTIONS are separated by an equals sign. Multiple option/value pairs in ASAN_OPTIONS can be specified by separating them with a colon.

Note that setting environment variables has no effect on the parent process.

```
/* To allow malloc to return NULL in C: */
setenv("ASAN_OPTIONS", "allocator_may_return_null=1", 1);

/* To turn the option back off: */
unsetenv("ASAN_OPTIONS");
```

In Bash:

```bash
env ASAN_OPTIONS=allocator_may_return_null=1 ./yourprogram arguments
```

For example, I use the following to turn leak checking off during build:

```bash
ASAN_OPTIONS=detect_leaks=0 make -j3
```

1. As allocator_may_return_null is a common flag, it can also be specified in the TSAN_OPTIONS, MSAN_OPTIONS, LSAN_OPTIONS, or UBSAN_OPTIONS environment variable.